# Migrate Data from Azure cosmos US region to European Region using data factory

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

I want to migrate records which has country column as one of the EU countries from US region cosmos DB to cosmos DB of West Europe.

I have multiple collections and I want to dynamically iterate through these collection, run queries "where country in ('abc')" and migrate/copy data to sink(cosmos of EU region).

How can I design a pipeline using azure data factory ?
I tried following this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-bulk-copy-portal.

I am not able to find a dynamic content for all tables from cosmos as source.

Thanks,
Rihuk

Answer (score 1):

- A Cosmos DB should be created in **European Region** and need to make that as a sink in copy activity in Azure Data Factory.
- Below are the steps to create Cosmos DB for which you need to create 2 linked services one in **US region** that should be source database and other should be sink database in European Region.

[image: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/media/doc-common-process/new-linked-service.png]

- Below image will help you in configuring service details, testing connection and creating new linked service.

[image: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/media/connector-azure-cosmos-db/configure-azure-cosmos-db-linked-service.png]

- Here is the [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-cosmos-db?tabs=data-factory) regarding Copy and Transform data in Azure Cosmos DB.
- Also, you can Refer Azure CosmosDB container [link](https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip334.html) if you are using Open API.

Comment: Thanks . I need the same activity to run for a list of collection (20 different collections).